# more than one function from jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui in my website. I'm trying to us jquery ui for showing popup and for datepicker, but only popup is works.

So my question is: how can I use jquery both for popup and datepicker.

Here's my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/HE4Ud/):

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        }
    });
    $("#opener").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
$(function () {

    $(".from").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/cal.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,

        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $(".to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        },
        altField: "#alternate",
        altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"
    });
    $(".to").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/cal.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,

        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $(".from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        },
        altField: "#alternate1",
        altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"
    });
});
```

Comment: show your code and live site or fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge your jQuery-UI initiliazer in single method. As;

```
$(function () {

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        // Properties
    });

    $(".from").datepicker({
       // Properties
    });

    $(".to").datepicker({
       // Properties
    });

});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/n7c6u/

Comment: in fiddle also check-in and check-out date textbox do not have datepicker.

Comment: My Pleasure! If you want to open date-picker on icon click then change buttonImage property value by your project icon.